# Unable to Update Android studio from 1.3.1 to 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently i am running android studio 1.3.1, when i try to check for updates manually Help> Check for Update it shows "Currently running latest version" though 1.5 is available .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1.4 currently in beta channel please see [here](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable). Your studio probably configured to take the stable release. 
However you can configure your studio take the beta channel in File > Settings > Updates. Details [here](http://tools.android.com/preview-channel).

Comment: Thanks Eugene ,Saved my time.. . :)